# Supposing B is orientable, and supposing A#B is homeomorphic to C#B, does it follow that A and C are homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology

Ok, I know this the statement "if A#B is homeomorphic to C#B, then A and C are homeomorphic" is not valid for n-manifolds A, B, and C if B is non-orientable.

Ex) T#P is homeomorphic to (P#P)#P, where T is the torus and P is the projective plane. However, T is not homeomorphic to P#P.

So, my question is: if we restrict B to being an orientable n-manifold, is the statement "if A#B is homeomorphic to C#B, then A and C are homeomorphic" valid for any n-manifolds A and C, be they orientable or non-orientable?

Comment: No, once $n\ge 4$, see for instance proposition 5.2.4 in "4-manifolds and Kirby Calculus" by Gompf and Stipsicz.

Comment: $\Bbb{CP}^2$ blown up twice is homeomorphic to $\Bbb{CP}^1 \times \Bbb{CP}^1$ blown up once. Blowing up is the same as taking connected sum with $\overline{\Bbb{CP^2}}$. Everything is orientable (and oriented) here.